# Questions about setuid

Tags: c, setuid

I have a problem with running the following C program:

```
#include<unistd.h>

void main()
{
    if (access("/root/main.c",R_OK)==0)
    {
        printf("/root/main.c can be read\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("can't be read\n");
    }
}
```

When I run the executable as root, I can get the output:

```
/root/main.c can be read
```

But when I set the executable's permissions to `4755`, and run it as normal user, I only get the output:

```
can't be read
```

Is there any error in my protocol?

Comment: who is the owner and group of the file

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the first 4? It does not match https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions

Comment: @TomdeGeus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setuid_and_setgid_on_executables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`access` ignores setuid/setgid bits. This is by design.

Quoting from `man 2 access` on Linux:

> The check is done using the calling process's *real* UID and GID,
>          rather than the effective IDs as is done when actually attempting an
>          operation (e.g., `open(2)`) on the file.  Similarly, for the root user,
>          the check uses the set of permitted capabilities rather than the set
>          of effective capabilities; and for non-root users, the check uses an
>          empty set of capabilities.
>
> This allows set-user-ID programs and capability-endowed programs to
>          easily determine the invoking user's authority.  In other words,
>          `access()` does not answer the "can I read/write/execute this file?"
>          question.  It answers a slightly different question: "(assuming I'm a
>          setuid binary) can *the user who invoked me* read/write/execute this
>          file?", which gives set-user-ID programs the possibility to prevent
>          malicious users from causing them to read files which users shouldn't
>          be able to read.

If you want to know whether your process can actually open a file for reading, just `open()` it and handle the error, if any. (This also avoids a race condition.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helps me a lot.